# Can't connect after changing my wireless card mac address

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, mac-address

I've tried to change my wireless card's mac address but it's not working. I did it using [TMACv6](https://technitium.com/tmac/) (Technitium), [MacMakeUp](http://www.gorlani.com/portal/projects/mac-makeup-the-original) and the registry by following [this tutorial](http://snaked-bytes.blogspot.fr/2011/12/how-to-change-your-mac-address-in.html) but I always have the same issue(s) :

1. Sometimes, when I disable and re-enable my wireless device, Windows 8 crashes with this error : `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`. Then my computer reboots and the changed mac address is reset, so the network works but with the original mac address.
2. But when there is not this error, and when my mac address is successfully changed, if I try to connect to my router, my laptop won't connect to the WiFi.

Maybe my wireless card has a security that knows when there was a change? Maybe my wireless card is not compatible with changing mac address?

Is there something to do in the registry?

PS : I have an ASUS laptop, and the wireless card is a `802.11n Wireless LAN Card` by `Ralink Technology, Corp.` (manufacturer is `Mediatek, Inc.`). If you need more informations, ask me !

Comment: What is the make and model of your wireless card?